# Force blackberry game to always use landscape mode

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am porting a game from **j2me** to **blackberry**. In j2me there is a way to change orientation. but I don't know how to do it in blackberry. If I am using

```
net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);
```

Its giving error. Please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't call the `setAcceptableDirections` method before you enter the event dispatcher. Here's what i did in my `Screen` and it works:

```
protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
    super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
    Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: That's interesting - I have found that it works before entering the event dispatcher. But I like your idea of hooking the onUiEngineAttached() method.